# Calculate value greater than 0 in date/time query

Tags: sql, predicate

The statement below is part of a query I am currently working with in trying to determine the number of days that has passed since the original appointment date.

```
, DATEDIFF(D, a.AppointmentDate, GETDATE()) as DaysSinceApptDate
```

However, I get both negative and positive results. I need to change the query to include only positive results. So, anything greater than 0 is what I want.

My entire query is:

```
    DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2014-12-1'

    SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ORDERS.ORDERDATE, PatientProfile.searchname) as   RowNumber
 , PatientProfile.searchname as PatientName
 , PatientProfile.Birthdate
 , ORDERS.ORDERDATE as OrderDate
 , DATEDIFF(D, ORDERS.ORDERDATE, ORDERS.DB_UPDATED_DATE) AS DaysToCurrentStatus
 , ORDERS.DESCRIPTION as ReferralType
 , CASE WHEN ORDERS.STATUS = 'U' Then 'Unsigned' 
    WHEN ORDERS.STATUS = 'H' Then 'Admin Hold'
    WHEN ORDERS.STATUS = 'S' Then 'InProcess'
    WHEN ORDERS.STATUS = 'C' Then 'Complete'
    WHEN ORDERS.STATUS = 'X' Then 'Cancelled'
    ELSE NULL END AS Status
 , df.ListName as OrderingProvider
 , ORDERS.DB_UPDATED_DATE as LastUpdated
 , ORDERS.CLINCOMMENTS as Comments
 , RIGHT(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(ORDERS.CLINCOMMENTS,CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),'')), 18) as AppointmentDate /* Get rid of carriage returns, line breaks, and trailing spaces */
 , Coordinator = CASE
    WHEN ORDERS.ADMINCOMMENTS like 'Leticia%' then 'Leticia'
    WHEN ORDERS.ADMINCOMMENTS = 'Je%' then 'Jessica'
    WHEN ORDERS.ADMINCOMMENTS = 'Da%' then 'Dahlia'
    WHEN ORDERS.ADMINCOMMENTS = 'sandra' OR ORDERS.ADMINCOMMENTS = 'sc' THEN 'Sandra'
    ELSE NULL END
 , LOCREG.ABBREVNAME as Location
 INTO #TEMP
 FROM   (CentricityPS.dbo.PatientProfile PatientProfile 
 INNER JOIN CentricityPS.dbo.ORDERS ORDERS 
    ON PatientProfile.PId=ORDERS.PID) 
 INNER JOIN DoctorFacility df
    ON ORDERS.AUTHBYUSRID = DF.PVId
 INNER JOIN CentricityPS.dbo.LOCREG LOCREG 
    ON DF.LocationId=LOCREG.LOCID
 WHERE  ORDERS.ORDERDATE >= @StartDate
    AND ORDERS.ORDERTYPE='R' /*Referral*/

    AND ORDERS.XID= 1000000000000000000

    ORDER BY OrderingProvider

/* Cast only valid dates as AppointmentDates*/
SELECT RowNumber, CAST(AppointmentDate as DateTime) as AppointmentDate
INTO #Appts
FROM #TEMP
WHERE ISDATE(AppointmentDate) = 1

SELECT
    t.PatientName
    , t.Birthdate
    , t.OrderDate
    , t.ReferralType
    , t.Status
    , t.OrderingProvider
    , t.Comments
    , a.AppointmentDate as AppointmentDate
    , DATEDIFF(D, a.AppointmentDate, GETDATE()) as DaysSinceApptDate 
    , t.Coordinator
    , t.Location

FROM #TEMP t
    LEFT JOIN #Appts a
        ON a.RowNumber = t.RowNumber
```

DROP TABLE #TEMP, #Appts
    Is there a way to do this in the SQL query?

Comment: which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: `where a.AppointmentDate >  GETDATE()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your table has both future and past appointments. Use `WHERE a.AppointmentDate < GETDATE()` to get only past appointments. This will eliminate the negative results.